# does the series $\sum | \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} (1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}) |$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Does the series $$S_n = \sum \bigg{|} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \left(1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \bigg{|}$$ converge?

I could arrive at $S_n = \sum \bigg{|}  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right) \bigg{|}$.

And I didn't know what to do from here.

Comment: see $$\bigg{|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \bigg{|} \geq \bigg{|} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \bigg{|} - \bigg{|} \frac{1}{n} \bigg{|} $$.

Comment: But then how can we use this? It's the difference of two Diveregent Rienmann series but honestly I didn't know what to do

Comment: Just take summation both the sides and we know that RHS diverges so the LHS.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you arrived at this inequality?

Comment: It is just triangle inequality. See for even $n$ clearly LHS $>$ RHS and for odd $n$ both are equal.

Comment: I was trying to see what wolfram alpha will say about this but nothing happened [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%7C+%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5En%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D+%5Cleft%281%2B+%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5En%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D%5Cright%29+%7C)

Comment: But the triangle inequality is $|a+b| <= |a| + |b|$.

Comment: Isn't it obvious to write triangle inequality as $|a| + |b| \geq |a+b| \geq |a| - |b|$

Comment: bit of a spoiler, but it's a trick I think you should learn to spot: you should note that for sufficiently large $n$ we have $2 \sqrt n \le n$ and then use Lucky's hint. It's not entirely trivial, note that the sum of $\frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n + 1}$ actually converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $n > \sqrt{n}$ for all $n \geq 2$. Let us rewrite the sum
$S_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |(-1)^n||\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{(-1)^n}{n}| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}|$

Note that since $n > \sqrt{n}$ the expression $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ is positive. Thus,

$S_n= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}  = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + L  = \infty$.
Note that since

Since the sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = L$ converges, and the sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ does.

Comment: Why is $S_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{1}{n}| = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: Added a bit more steps to the proof.